# Linq - Range variable hides a variable in an enclosing block

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have several Linq statements in a public procedure (here are 2 of them):

```
'this one gets us table like this: "number of tickets, day"
Dim ticketsCreated = From ticket In CreatedTickets
   Group ticket By GroupKey = New With {Key .IssueDate = CDate(ticket.Date).Date}
   Into g = Group Select New 
       With {Key .IssuesCount = g.Count(), Key .IssueDate = GroupKey.IssueDate}

'this one gets us table like this: "number of tickets, day"
Dim ticketsClosed = From ticket In ClosedTickets
    Group ticket By GroupKey = New With {Key .IssueDate = CDate(ticket.Date).Date}
    Into g = Group Select New 
         With {Key .IssuesCount = g.Count(), Key .IssueDate = GroupKey.IssueDate}
```

I get the follwoing error on GroupKey in both statements:

```
Range variable hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, 
or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression
```

I do not have a variable named GroupKey declared anywhere outside of my Linq statements.

Comment: If you change one to eg `GroupKey2`, does the error on the other one go away? If so, that suggests they are conflicting with *each other*

Comment: I doubt that they conflict with each other, but it's worth a try. If it doesn't work, try renaming both to GroupKey2. If it works than you do have a GroupKey variable somewhere.

Comment: What are `CreatedTickets` and `ClosedTickets`? Any chance that the duplicated range variable occurs in their source?